Is there a way to customize the ckeditor4 toobar icons to swedish locale icons.?
One of our clients are looking for specific icons based on thier locale, but as mentioned in the ckeditor Available Localizations Setting Editor UI Language, there isnt any changes to the icons our swedish clients are asking for,
So the change in icon they are expecting are
F (fet stil) instead of B
K (kursiv) instead of I
ab (with strike through) (genomstruken) instead of S(with strike through)
U is OK-starts with the same letter as in Swedish "understruken"
We are taking the ckeditor4 img icons and loading it into our application, but for the swedish locale we expect :
F (fet stil) instead of B
K (kursiv) instead of I
ab (with strike through) (genomstruken) instead of S(with strike through)
U is OK-starts with the same letter as in Swedish "understruken"This is my Image
